# Dynamic Time Warping - building a distance matrix with any distance that we want?

Tags: time-series, algorithms, dynamic-time-warping

I am new to Dynamic Time Warping. I understand that we build a distance matrix and then try to find the cheapest path from starting to ending point. Typically euclidean distance is used to calculate the distance, but one can use other weightings.

Comment: Cheapest path? Some other adjective is needed.

Comment: People also use Manhattan Distance, plus there are lots of other distribution based distance metrics like Mahalanobis etc

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping helps. *Least cost* refers to a loss function, although one might think this is a synonym for *cheapest* that would not be vernacular. What loss function is used would depend on what is most expedient for the particular data being analyzed.